# Usage of "done" vs. "done with."

Tags: grammar

I've always found it irksome when people form sentences such as "I'm done my homework." It is of my understanding that you are never *done* something, but rather you are *done with* something.

Am I right to be bothered by this?

Comment: There is a bunch of info specifically about this usage in the Yale Grammatical Diversity Project here: https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/done-my-homework

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're right to be bothered.

> *I'm done my homework*

is not acceptable English.

> I'm done with my homework
>
> I have done my homework
>
> I did my homework

are fine.  *Done* is called the past participle of the verb *do*, and *done* needs a helper word like *have* or *had* when used as a verb.

Comment: Note that _I've done_ is a normal contraction of _I have done_ and is fine to use in speech.  A novice learner might not have not have noticed that _I've_ and not _I'm_ is used in this context.

Comment: There is a bunch of info specifically about this usage in the Yale Grammatical Diversity Project here: https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/done-my-homework

Answer (score 4):

I'm done my homework is completely acceptable in some regions.  Canada, some regions of Philadelphia, NJ, and New Hampshire. Language changes, so I would say when entire countries are now finding a certain construct acceptable, that's enough to say that it is indeed acceptable :)

Comment: Here's a [citation for this](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/done-my-homework) from a comment on another answer. Ugh. :-)

Answer (score 3):

> My homework's done.
>
> I've done my homework.
>
> I'm done with my homework.

All are acceptable.

I'm done my homework? Not if it's for English class.

Answer (score 2):

This grammatical construction is popular in Canadian English. To me as a Canadian I was surprised to find that it was not standard. I have found someone say that it's frequently used in Philadelphia but not Pittsbourgh. Odd... It can be found in some regions of the United States, but not all. Linguistic data on the internet is hard to come by.

Comment: I've just done a Google Ngram search for 'I'm done my homework' and there are no examples in their extensive corpus.

Comment: The 1.9-billion-word Corpus of Global Web-Based English has 16 citations for "I'm done my ...", six from Canada, two from the USA and one each from Australia, Bangladesh, Britain, Nigeria, New Zealand, the Philippines and  Singapore

Answer (score 1):

'have done' is the present perfect of 'do'

> I've done my homework

*I'm done* is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm done my homework is incorrect.  If you want to say it with your buddies in Philadelphia, no one will make a big deal out of it because it is a regional quirk.  Do not write it in anything academic or professional though.  Also, say it to someone outside the small area of the country where it is considered acceptable and people will cringe.

Answer (score -1):

In the classroom & Academic writing is not acceptable. However, in spoken form may be accepted _ to convey meaning

Answer (score -1):

I am (I'm) is the present tense.  To say I'm done my homework looks a bit of a mess and incorrect.  The sentense combines present tense with past "done".  Therefore something in the sentence seems obviously obsolete.  Or more than required. Unnessessary.  In some instances to say I am done would be correct. But the meaning would mean something of a negative action had just happened to the first person.

Some intresting (to me) examples copyied and pasted from http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/to_be.htm illustrating

**Unnecessary Uses of “To Be”**

He wanted a medication (that was) prescribed by a physician. 
She recognized the officer (who was) chasing the crook. 
Anyone (who is) willing to work hard will succeed in this program. 
(It was) Alberto ( who) told the principal about the students' prank. (Notice that the “it was” brought special emphasis to “Alberto,” an emphasis that is somewhat lost by this change.) 
A customer( who is) pleased is sure to return. A pleased customer is sure to return.

Present Tense use of "do"
I do my homework on Saturdays.
I am doing my homework.
You do your homework on Saturday's.
You are doing your homework.
He does his homework on Saturdays.
He is doing his homework.
She does her homework on Saturdays
It does its homework.
I am done doing this homework.